# How to parse elements of a string and add them into another string

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a string like this

```
String[] tokens = {"Word0", "Word1","Word3"};
```

and then I have an arraylist like this

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList();
a.add("This will not change");
```

What I want to do is to be able to create a new arraylist ,b ,that puts these two together such that: Element 0 of b is "Word0 This will not change"
Element 1 of b is "Word0 Word1 This will not change"
Element 3 of b is "Word0 Word1 Word3 This will not change"

I played around with for loops and tried to somehow concatenate the strings but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: `"I played around with for loops and tried to somehow concatenate the strings but I couldn't figure it out."` -- consider showing us your attempts. It will help us understand what you may be doing wrong, and gain you a little bit of respect for showing your efforts.

Comment: Note that this looks for all the world like you're asking us to solve a homework assignment for you.

Comment: Specifically one that appears like it should be solved recursively. Also, **please** change `new ArrayList();` to `new ArrayList<>();`; raw types are so last millennium.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
String[] tokens = {"Word0","Word1","Word2"};
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
a.add("This will not change");

ArrayList<String> b = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
{
    String add = "";
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
    {
        add += tokens[j];
        add += " ";
    }
    b.add( (add + a.get(0)) );
}
```

This is tested and works.